# 2 wordpress site communications

Tags: wordpress, communication

I have 2 independent site that I need theme to share some information.

I create in one "MAIN" site a custom post type.

I need to have in the second website "SECOND" the same info for this specific post type.
Is there a way that my site "SECOND" can communicate with the one that have the post type "MAIN".

I'm trying to prevent double maintenance on those 2 site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WordPress XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support), I think it will be quite a lot of code to write but it's doable. See:

- [How to create new post with photo attached in WordPress using XMLRPC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7607473/1287812)
- [How to get WordPress posts from a single category using XML-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25478038/1287812)